# Ideas on starting a GCE instance from a local Web server?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I use Google Compute Enginer (GCE) to handle a Django Web application for my own use, which I used to host myself but have found works better for me in the cloud. I find myself wanting to launch an instance using my Web browser to avoid dropping to a terminal. (The main reason to do this isn't to avoid typing, it's to allow me to access my work from non-Linux devices such as my tablet computer.)

I would like to start and stop a GCE instance via cgi-bin scripts which I would place on my local Web server, but have been thwarted by perfectly valid security-related Apache configuration issues:

- It's difficult to run scripts as myself, as opposed to the default (for Debian) www-data user.
- I don't want to maintain multiple installs of the Google Cloud SDK just for this purpose,  but am willing to try it if there is no more elegant solution.
- I tried generating an API call directly via a Python script, as opposed to going through gcutil, but this failed because the www-data user cannot import the Python library "httplib2." (The import statements before this one work fine.) I can import httplib2 just fine as myself, so somewhere in my install this has been disabled for www-data. (The instance starts if I run it in my own environment, as opposed to in the Web server's environment, so I know the script works.)

I am looking for out-of-the-box suggestions for starting and stopping GCE instances from the environment of a Web server. Alternately, perhaps someone knows how to get httplib2 imported into a Python script running in the environment of www-data in Debian. (Perhaps I found a bug? Or perhaps this is done for a good reason other than "why would anyone want to import httplib2 from Apache?")

Comment: Has this been solved yet? I'm curious if you're trying to replicate the functionality of the [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) which already lets you start/stop instances from a web UI and handles all the authentication, etc. so you don't need to use `gcloud` if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [API](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/) for managing your Compute Engine resources from a web application. It has full support including [starting](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/insert) and [stopping](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/delete) instances, as you mention in your post.

You can get the httplib2 library from https://code.google.com/p/httplib2